# Does Tomcat destroy too early ServletContext on shutdown?

Tags: java, tomcat

On shutdown, I expect that Tomcat stops accepting new requests (and it does!) and finalizes ongoing requests successfully. Unfortunately ServletContext (`Servlet.destroy`, `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed`, ...) is destroyed before finalization of ongoing requests.
These ongoing requests which rely on ServletContext will fail and potentially **corrupt data**! Context should be destroyed only after ongoing requests are processed.

Diving into code, `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal` method reveals indeed that ServletContext is destroyed (`engine.stop()` statement) before shutting down (`connector.stop()` statement) the thread pool for requests (ThreadPoolExecutor).

I did find `StandardContext.unloadDelay` parameter (Number of ms that the container will wait for servlets to unload. If not specified, the default value is 2000 ms.) which may be the solution...

Do you know how to get this issue fixed differently?

How to reproduce:

```
@WebServlet(name = "StartStopServlet", displayName = "StartStopServlet", urlPatterns = "/execute")
public class StartStopServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    private ExpensiveResource resource = null;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("----> initializing StartStopServlet ...");
        super.init();

        resource = new ExpensiveResource();
        resource.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // simulating time consuming operation before invoking ExpensiveService
        System.out.println("----> preparing parameters for ExpensiveResource call. It will take about 6 secs");

        // Now is the time to stop Tomcat: invoke shutdown.sh (or shutdown.bat)

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // produces NullPointerException if ServletContext is destroyed
        Model result = resource.doWork();

        // Preparing response...
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("----> destroying StartStopServlet ...");
        super.destroy();

        resource.disconnect();
        resource = null;
    }
}
```

`resource.doWork()` statement is invoked after `destroy()` method.